# Clip video with Azure Media Services without encoding and download clip

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I would like to create a clip from an existing video asset using Azure Media Services without encoding

This can be done using a Dynamic Manifest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-dynamic-manifest

It works but I also want to download the clip using the manifest. Is this possible somehow ?

Or only if it is re-encoded ? like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-azure-media-clipper-submit-job#submitting-encoding-job-to-create-video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - do download the clip, you would need to re-encode. You can submit a clipping Job directly - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#trim_video) for more information